# Use Azure Batch for non-parallel work? Is there a better option?

Tags: azure-virtual-machine, azure-batch

I have a scenario where our Azure App Service needs to run a job every night. The job cannot scale to multiple machines -- it involves downloading a large data file, and does special processing on it (only takes a couple minutes). Special software will be required to be installed as well. A lot of memory will be needed on the machine for the computation, therefore I was thinking one of the Ev-series machines. For these reasons, I cannot run the job as a web job on the Azure App Service, and I need to delegate it elsewhere.

Anyway, I have experience with Azure Batch so at first I was thinking of Azure Batch. But I am not sure this makes sense for my scenario because the work cannot scale to multiple machines. Does it make sense to have a pool with a single node and single vm on the node? When I need to do the work, an Azure web job enqueues the job, and the pool automatically sizes from 0 to 1?

Are there better options out there? I was look to see if there are any .NET libraries to spin up a single VM and start executing work on it, then disable the VM when done, but I couldn't find anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Azure Batch, the scenario of a single VM in a single pool is valid. [Azure Container Instances](https://azure.microsoft.com/services/container-instances/) or [Azure Functions](https://azure.microsoft.com/services/functions/) would appear to be a better fit, however, if you can provision the appropriate VM sizes for your workload.

As you suggested, you can combine Azure Functions/Web Jobs to enqueue the work to an Azure Batch Job. If you have [autoscaling](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/batch/batch-automatic-scaling) or an [autopool](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/batchservice/job/add#autopoolspecification) set on the Azure Batch Pool or Job, respectively, then the work will be processed and the compute resources will be deallocated after (assuming you have the correct settings in-place).

Comment: Thanks so much for the pointer to Azure Container Instances! I now deploy my now-docker application to an ACI and it is a perfect fit for my scenario. I ended up using an Azure WebJob to start up the ACI at night. Thanks a lot!